# Slack values in Data Envelopment Analysis

Tags: econometrics, excel

We're using Excel Solver to model a DEA problem.  We've worked with a few resources and feel confident that the model is returning correct results but I need some help interpreting them.

When solver completes its analysis, it provides an answer report that gives the slack found in some of the constraints -- which are binding and which are not.

Here's a sample result for a DMU that was found to be inefficient when Solving to Minimize the Inputs:

```
              WeightedSum             Outputs = DMU
           of Reference Set          Inputs = DMU * E   Slack
Output1        2,892,230     >=        2,892,230        binding
Output2        66,229,077    >=        66,229,077       binding
Output3        9,724,273     >=        5,372,010        4,352,263
Output4        3,123,300     >=        2,511,864        611,436
Output5        21,609        >=        16,039           5,570
Output6        120,527       >=        33,234           87,292
Output7        8,548         >=        2,769            5,779
Output8        17,314        >=        12,605           4,709
Output9        748           >=        616              132
 Input1        19,775        <=        23,314           3,539
 Input2        9,132         <=        9,132            binding
 Input3        20,028        <=        143,604          123,576
 Input4        74,293        <=        74,293           binding
 Input5        15,558        <=        15,558           binding
```

Is it correct to assert that those inputs found to be binding could not be further optimized but those that contained slack are where the inefficiencies are found?

Can the same be said for Outputs? or does that work the opposite?

Or is slack just a bi-product of the analysis and not relevant?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As I understand data envelopment analysis, you optimize efficiency of the decision making unit (DMU) subject to a set of constraints on input availability and output requirements.

Since you have identified the maximum efficiency the non-binding input constraints indicate that the amount of slack in inputs is unnecessary expenditure and can be avoided without sacrificing efficiency.

However, the slack with respect to output constraints needs to be dealt with more carefully. If you do not care about producing more than the minimum required then the slack on the output constraints is irrelevant. However, if you do care about producing more than the minimum required then perhaps you should either penalize excess output suitably or transform the greater than equal constraints into an equality constraint.

Do note that imposing penalties or converting your output constraints into equality constraints may decrease efficiency but that is a trade-off you need to take keeping the context in mind.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to assert that those inputs found to be binding could not be further optimized but those that contained slack are where the inefficiencies are found?

First of all, this is a multivariate problem, so it is really hard to conclude anything about individual inputs/outputs. However I would rather say the opposite - the inputs where the constraints are binding could be further optimized except you are hitting a boundary condition that stops you from doing so, while inputs where there is some slack left found an optimum.

As a simple example, suppose you want to minimize $(x-3)^2+y$ with $x \geq 0$, $y\geq 0$ constraints. You will find the optimum at $x=3$, $y=0$ with $x$ having a slack of 3, and $y$ being a binding constraint. That's because you could get smaller values of your output if $y$ were allowed to be negative, but you prohibited that. On the other hand, $x$ would not benefit from allowing negative values.

Of course, one cannot make far-reaching conclusions, because minimizing $(x-3)^2+y^2$ would give the same results even though having negative $y$'s would not help. Similarly, it is possible to create a function where the global minimum would occur for a negative $x$ even though there is a local minimum at $x=3$. Additionally, with constraints on the output, even inputs with slack might not be local optima because one of the output constraints could have kicked in. You can check the latter by looking at derivatives (I think Solver might show them) - a zero derivative implies a local optimum (or inflection point, but that's less likely).

Sorry for the rambling answer, but the main point is that if your problem is sufficiently complex, then any simple interpretation is likely be wrong in some cases.